# Counter with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

It is a newbie question, I am trying to make a counter using jquery and this the code that I got from a tutorial on youtube, but it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http//code.jquery.com/jquery- 1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="counter">0</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;

    setinterval("timer()", 1000);

    function timer() {
        counter++;
        $('#counter').text(counter);
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The function name is [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)(note capital `I`) and not `setinterval`
2. Also, don't use `string` as parameter to the `setInterval`. // Not error, but it is good practice
3. Also, the URL of jQuery is wrong, contains space in the jquery and version.

   ```
   http//code.jquery.com/jquery- 1.7.1.min.js
   //                           ^
   ```

Demo:

```js
var counter = 0;
setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  counter++;
  $('#counter').text(counter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

Comment: and +1 for using the non-string version (although it also works, I feel the string version should be banned like `eval`!) :)

Comment: @MaryE There was space, that was making the URL incorrect, and because of this jQuery was not loaded

Answer (score 1):

try it cause you are using a local variable try to use an global like this an your are using `seinterval()` that doesn't exists use `setInterval()` i'am using [jquery labery](http://jquery.com)

```
<div id="counter">0</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

   window.counter = 0;

   setInterval(function(){timer()},1000);

   function timer() {

     window.counter++;

   $('#counter').text(window.counter);

}
<script>
```